# Altering code to paste only cell value from an active cell

Tags: copy, paste, newrow

This is what I currently have:

```
If Sheet6.Range("j8").Value <> 0 Then

Sheet6.Range("j8").Copy Sheet6.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End If

Sheet6.Range("J8").ClearContents
```

But the problem is that I only need to copy the values, not the entire format (I have tried with pastespecial xlpastevalues, but have had little success)..and the other problem that I have is that in order for this macro to work, I have to click on another cell (it can't be active)..but I need it to work while the cell is still active..Please help, thanks